# Change oracle db user password without knowing existing password PHP

Tags: php, oracle, reset, forgot-password

I have a request to supply the functionality for users to change their Oracle password through their web interface. In the case of an expired password it's fine, but I haven't been able to find a solution if the user has forgotten their password. I've had a look at oci_password_change but the old password is required.

Would there be a way to create an 'admin' db connection and use that to reset the Oracle password for a specific user without knowing the previous password?

Answer (score 2):

A user with the `alter user` system privilege can run:

```
ALTER USER user_name IDENTIFIED BY new_password;
```

Comment: Thank you, would I use this as a query?

Comment: You could run a PL/SQL block that uses `execute immediate` i.e.: `begin execute immediate 'ALTER USER user_name IDENTIFIED BY new_password; end;' end;`